# How do I remove extra white spaces between sentences in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I have strings that have extra white spaces between sentences. The string is intended to be human readable so should only have two spaces between the period and the beginning of the next sentence.

Spaces between words within a sentence should remain a single space and extra spaces should be removed.

How do I do this in Ruby ?

Comment: It is impossible to (deterministically) do this. If you want to do it with results that are statistically likely to be correct, then you need to do natural language processing; that would need much more of code than what can be reasonably put as an answer to a thread like this.

Comment: Describing it doesn't do nearly as much good as providing an example of your input and expected output. You also need to show us some code you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use `. ! ?` to separate sentences, you can use `squeeze` to deal with those extra white spaces between words first, then add two spaces after `. ! ?` using `gsub`.

```
p = "The first line.    The   second   line! The   third  line?"
p.squeeze(" ").gsub(/([.?!]) */,'\1  ')
=>"The first linee.  The second line!  The third line?  "
```

Comment: Actually I like this way more.

Comment: If you had applied `squeeze`, then there will not be consecutive spaces any more. The `*` in your regex is redundant; it should be replaced by `?`.

Comment: Your code will convert `Mr._Bean` (`_` indicates a space) into `Mr.__Bean`, `i.e.` into `i.__e.__` and `Oh man ...` into `Oh man .__.__.__`.

Comment: @sawa .. Yes, I know this problem, so I could only assuming the sentences will be divided by `. ! ?`. This approach cannot process natural language.

Comment: Great thanks. I think thus can address it in most cases. The situation or Mr. Bean might come up in the future but this solves the immediate issues I believe. I will test it.

Comment: What is in quotes in squeeze a single space?

Comment: Can I add ellipses ... To the punctuation so that extra spaces aren't added?